# <<MenuSelect>> in Tcl/Tk 8.6.11 and on

Tags: menu, tcl, tk-toolkit, tcltk

I have a problem with MenuSelect event in Tcl/Tk 8.6.11 (tried in Linux, Debian 10.7).

In fact, it doesn't fire at all for the main and tearoff-ed menus. Though working fine in Tcl/Tk 8.6.9, and even in 8.6.11 - only while menus are not tearoff-ed.

A test code:

```
package require Tk
proc ::somehandler {w wt} {
  puts "Step [incr ::step]: $w / $wt, index=[$wt index active]"
}
set w [menu .m -tearoff 1]
$w add command -label {Item 1}
$w add command -label {Item 2}
bind $w <<MenuSelect>> [list ::somehandler $w %W]
pack [button .b -text "Click me" \
  -command {tk_popup .m [winfo pointerx .] [winfo pointery .]}]
```

I tried the following (idiotic though) replacement:

```
event delete <<MenuSelect>>
event add <<MenuSelect>> <Motion>
bind $w <<MenuSelect>> [list ::somehandler $w %W]
```

... with the same results.

Seemingly, it's related to menu pathes dealt in Tk somewhat tricky, as seen in the above example.

I'm too lazy to change a standard code at switching from 8.6.9 to 8.6.11/12, 8.7 etc.

TIA for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the fact that menus use clones for tearoffs and the menubar. From the [documentation](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/menu.html#M22):

> When  a  menu is set as a menubar for a toplevel window, or when a menu
> is torn off, a clone of the menu is made. This clone is a  menu  widget
> in  its  own  right,  but it is a child of the original. Changes in the
> configuration of the original are reflected in the clone. Additionally,
> any cascades that are pointed to are also cloned so that menu traversal
> will work right. Clones  are  destroyed  when  either  the  tearoff  or
> menubar goes away, or when the original menu is destroyed.

I can't remember how exactly clones are really named, but you don't normally interact with them directly; it's only with event handling that you ever really see them. (I've only ever had to deal with them when doing tooltips for menus.)

Normally, it's considered best to avoid using `<<MenuSelect>>` and instead just set a `-command` on the entries that can be selected (or to just set the model variables right for `checkbutton` and `radiobutton` entries). And avoid tearoffs entirely; they're a style of menu interaction that went out of fashion over 25 years ago.

Comment: That's the 8.7 docs, but menus have been functionally the same for a very long time; we see very little reason to change them. (Clones exist because a menu can be a tearoff, a menubar and a direct popup from a menubutton, all visible at the same time. You probably don't want to do that, but it's possible.)

Comment: Hi Donal, thank you for your answer, I hoped for it and got it. Though, alas, it is not satisfactory. I need not commands on menu items but to watch on their selections. It's all about showing tooltips for them. I have an advice by Csaba how to workaround this issue and after trying it I'll post it here as an answer, just for those who would need it too. Still, I hoped for a cardinal solution of this problem as it's a real bug imho introduced to Tk in 8.6.11.

Answer (score 0):

For Tk 8.6.11+, *bind Menu* should be used instead of *bind $w* (for individual menu items). It adds some acrobatics to an event handler that should calculate what's a menu item to be dealt with.

I.e. we have something like:

```
bind Menu <<MenuSelect>> [list ::somehandler %W]
```

The %W wildcard is passed to *::somehandler* as a "cloned" name, if the menu item is in a cloned menu.

And ::somehandler should calculate who is the %W in reality.

Csaba Nemethi advises to use a procedure like *clonename* (from utils.tcl of BWidget package). This procedure gets a clone name from a "normal" menu item's path.

Here is a bit modified version of it:

```
proc clonename {mnu} {
  # Gets a clone name of a menu.
  #   mnu - the menu's path
  # This procedure is borrowed from BWidget's utils.tcl.

  set path [set menupath {}]
  set found 0
  foreach widget [lrange [split $mnu .] 1 end] {
    if {$found || [winfo class "$path.$widget"] eq {Menu}} {
      set found 1
      append menupath # $widget
      append path . $menupath
    } else {
      append menupath # $widget
      append path . $widget
    }
  }
  return $path
}
```

As an example of use, see *test.tcl* of:

http://chiselapp.com/user/aplsimple/repository/baltip/zip/trunk/baltip.zip

Thank you Donal and Csaba for your hints.